# Locating header file

Tags: c, linux, header-files

I have a trivial problem that one of my source file in my project has included a header file as

```
#include "abc.h"
```

It does not have that header file in that directory but has a symbolic link to another directory where it is created after building another code. I'm encountering an error while building it as

```
catastrophic error : could not open the source file "abc.h".
```

So should it be able to locate header file correctly with symbolic link or I need to copy it in the same folder?

Comment: Symbolic links should be completely transparent to the application.

Comment: Are you sure the file has actually been built at the time you are compiling your source file (is your build order correct, see your makefile etc). And always worth independently checking that everything is as you think it is by typing, e.g., `head abc.h` in the directory where your source file lives.

Comment: Ya my build order is correct and that header file is in the directory where my object files are stored. I have a symbolic link to that location. Can there be any other possible reason I am missing or it is not possible to guess that without looking at the code

Comment: you may add additional sources and header paths to the make file

Comment: Can copying that header file to this specific directory work ?